# transaction loop of parameter from C# to MySQL Database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I need to pass data from UI throw code behind using Entity and BAL, DAL and DBHelper layers.

I store the path as list of data and send it from code behind To BAL to DAL
The Code I have inn DAL is

```
public static bool InsertFile(List<GSFile> files)
    {
        try
        {
            using (DBHelper helper = new DBHelper())
            {
                foreach (var obj in files)
                {
                    GSFile query = new GSFile();
                    query.Name = obj.Name;
                    query.Hash = obj.Hash;
                    query.Path = obj.Path;
                    helper.AddParameter("@parmName", obj.Name);
                    helper.AddParameter("@parmPath", obj.Path);
                    helper.AddParameter("@parmHash", obj.Hash);
                    helper.SetStoredProcedureName("SP_Files_Insert");
                    return helper.ExecuteNonQuerys(query);
                }
                //return clearquery;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

The Code in DBHelper is:

```
public bool ExecuteNonQuerys(GSFile files)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var item in files)
            {
                mySqlCommand.Parameters[item.key].Value = item.value;
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

I need help to make this code work. I mean how to use this statement ...

```
 mySqlCommand.Parameters[item.key].Value = item.value;
```

... to change the parameter value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When send list of objects then it should make foreach loop for each item in the object.

```
foreach (var file in files)
    {
      foreach(var item in file)
            {
        mySqlCommand.Parameters[item.key].Value = item.value;
            }
     }
```